# JavaScript XHR - "responseType" Property vs "Content-Type" Header

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, content-type

A quick question arose to me while creating a simple, shareable XHR implementation for upcoming project.

What would the difference be in specifying the `responseType` property as json rather than the Content-Type header? Would everything be okay down the line if I did BOTH?

Thanks in advance for any insight! Thought this might start a good conversation.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 4):

The `Content-type` header is the format of parameters that the client is sending to the server in the `POST` data. This defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, unless you send a `FormData` object, in which case it's `multipart/form-data`. If you send some other format (e.g. JSON) you should set the `Content-type` header appropriately.

`responseType` is the type of data that the server is sending to the client in its response.

Comment: So what's the function replacement of `responseType` in curl or python/requests? or corresponding request header?

Comment: The `Accept:` header specifies the types of responses that you're willing to receive.

Comment: I tried the `Accept` header with all kinds of related values but no lock, [here is my detailed context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62538257/1677041).

Comment: The effect of this header depends on the server application.

Comment: I don't have the developing or document privilege of the server, but the exported curl command and network inspector really show the `Accept` as `*/*`, so I think the `blob` setting should be otherwhere.